# What is the correct name for overloading return values by const parameter value?

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript, when you use consts to return different types from function overloads, what is the technical name for that (and is it listed in the Language Specification as I can't find it!)

For example, the `getElementsByTagName` definition uses this technique:

```
//...
getElementsByTagName(name: "ul"): NodeListOf<HTMLUListElement>;
getElementsByTagName(name: "var"): NodeListOf<HTMLElement>;
getElementsByTagName(name: "video"): NodeListOf<HTMLVideoElement>;
getElementsByTagName(name: "wbr"): NodeListOf<HTMLElement>;
getElementsByTagName(name: string): NodeList;
//...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, one slight typo later and I got an error that answered my question.

These are called "Specialized overload signatures", or "specialized signatures" for short.

Once you know the name, it is easy to find them in section 3.7.2.4 of the TypeScript Language Specification.

Thanks to the compiler for this one.